# SKShapeNode not showing when SK3DNode is present

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, skshapenode

I have a problem with showing SKShapeNode when SK3DNode is present in the scene. When SKShapeNode is added to scene before adding SK3DNode, the SKShapeNode shows fine but adding SKShapeNode after SK3DNode, the SKShapeNode doesn't show up.

Also if the SK3DNode gets hidden for example by tapping the screen, afterwards added SKShapeNodes comes visible. Have anyone had this kind of problem? Below is the code of GameScene.swift I'm using where are two SKShapeNodes defined by path and two circles and one SK3DNode. SK3DNode gets hidden/visible when user taps screen so you can replicate the problem I explained above.

Notice that problem appears only on real device with iOS 10.3.2 (tested on iPhone 7). On simulator everything seems to work as charm, same thing with iPhone 4S with iOS 9.3.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import SceneKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var cylinder: SK3DNode!

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let label = SKLabelNode()
        label.text = "test"
        label.fontSize = 40
        label.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)
        self.addChild(label)

        self.addLine(yPosition: self.frame.height/4, color: SKColor.green)
        self.addCircle(xPosition: self.frame.width/4)
        self.addCylinder()
        self.addLine(yPosition: -self.frame.height/4, color: SKColor.blue)
        self.addCircle(xPosition: -self.frame.width/4)
    }

    private func addLine(yPosition: CGFloat, color: SKColor) {
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        let startPoint = CGPoint(x: -self.frame.width + 10, y: 0)
        let endPoint = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width - 10, y: 0)
        bezierPath.move(to: startPoint)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: endPoint)

        let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(path: bezierPath.cgPath)
        shapeNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: yPosition)
        shapeNode.strokeColor = color
        self.addChild(shapeNode)
    }

    private func addCylinder() {
        let cylinderGeometry = SCNCylinder(radius: 100, height: 40)
        let cylinderNode = SCNNode(geometry: cylinderGeometry)

        self.cylinder = SK3DNode(viewportSize: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300))
        self.cylinder.scnScene = SCNScene()
        self.cylinder.scnScene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cylinderNode)

        self.addChild(self.cylinder)
    }

    private func addCircle(xPosition: CGFloat) {
        let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 40)
        shapeNode.position = CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: 0)
        self.addChild(shapeNode)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.cylinder.isHidden = !self.cylinder.isHidden
    }
}
```

Comment: if you change shapeNode.position?

Comment: You mean shapeNode.zPosition? That actually works if you set shapeNode.zPosition to be negative. But there's still a problem if you want the SKShapeNode to be in front of SK3DNode. If you set cylinder.zPosition to be less than shapeNode.zPosition, original problem appears.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: It is a bug very likely. Playing with zPosition as described in my previous comment I got it working somewhere nicely. Fortunately my SK3DNode is quite small and I placed it where it won't be a problem if it comes top of other nodes.